# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: chart.jsProvider

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-scope, chart.js

I am trying to use this plugin https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js.
And I am getting this error (I don't think the problem is with the plugin instead it's in the way I'm doing the injection!!):

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: chart.jsProvider <- chart.js <- WhateverCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$injector/unpr?p0=chart.jsProvider%20%3C-hart.js%20%3C-%20WhateverCtrl
    at http://mega.app/scripts/vendor.js:9895:12
    at http://mega.app/scripts/vendor.js:13863:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://mega.app/scripts/vendor.js:14010:39)
    at http://mega.app/scripts/vendor.js:13868:45
    at getService (http://mega.app/scripts/vendor.js:14010:39)
    at invoke (http://mega.app/scripts/vendor.js:14042:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://mega.app/scripts/vendor.js:14059:27)
    at http://mega.app/scripts/vendor.js:18356:28
    at http://mega.app/scripts/vendor.js:44696:28
    at invokeLinkFn (http://mega.app/scripts/vendor.js:18113:9)
```

when I inject `chart.js` globally like below, I don't get any error. (keep reading)

```
angular.module('my-app', [
            'chart.js'      // <<<<<
            'ui.router',            
            'ngStorage',
            // ...
        ]);

})();
```

But from my understanding, it's recommended to inject this module only in the controllers that uses it, thus when I try to inject it in a controller like below, I get the error above.

```
angular
    .module('my-app')
    .controller('WhateverCtrl', ctrl);

ctrl.$inject = ['chart.js'];     // <<<<<

function ctrl() {
    var vm = this;

// ...
```

However if I remove the `$` from the injection line to `ctrl.inject = ['chart.js'];` I do get rid of the error, but `chart.js` wont work, because I guess I must pass it to the function `function ctrl() {` like this `function ctrl(chart.js) {` which of course causes an error due to the `.`.

Comment: Checking the demos, it looks like the provider to inject is called `ChartJsProvider`. [See here](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js#example) for an example. Also note that all configuration appears to be done in `app.config`, rather than in the controller.

Answer (score 5):

Since `angular-chart.js` is itself a module, it must be injected into the module and cannot be injected into the controller.

Comment: saved me from huge headache.. thumbs up dude

Comment: So how are the functions accessed in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

With JGOakley's clarification, I was able to discover this line in `angular-chart.js`

```
return angular.module('chart.js', [])
    .provider('ChartJs', ChartJsProvider)
```

To include this for use in your controller:

```
YourModule.$inject = ['ChartJs'];
```

This was a frustrating find, since I took this line to mean I could reference it as `chart`

```
define(['angular', 'chart'], factory);
```